Procedure Call is giving value in dbeaver but not from code call
Hi I am executing a stored procedure I am getting its result when I run it from dbeaver with my desired parameters correctly, whereas for the same procedure I am getting null resultant when I try to execute procedure from code.
Below are the code calls
procedurequery = entityManager.createNamedStoredProcedureQuery("UserManagementUsersReportModel.generate");
procedurequery.setParameter("START_DATE", formattedStartDate);
procedurequery.setParameter("END_DATE", formattedEndDate);
procedurequery.setParameter("DEF", parameters.get("def"));
procedurequery.setParameter("ABC", parameters.get("abc"));

    List<Report> ReportList = procedurequery.getResultList();

Moreover using entity as below:
@NamedStoredProcedureQuery(
        name = "Report.generate",
        procedureName = "REPORT",
        parameters = {
                @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "CREATED_START_DATE", type = String.class),
                @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "CREATED_END_DATE", type = String.class),
                @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "DEF", type = String.class),
                @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "ABC", type = String.class),
        },
        resultClasses = Report.class
)

I even got the parameters printed they are exactly the same I am using to run procedure from dbeaver
Parameter: ABC, Value: null
Parameter: CREATED_START_DATE, Value: 05-May-15
Parameter: DEF, Value: 1,2,79
Parameter: CREATED_END_DATE, Value: 08-May-24
Below is the query I am using in stored procedure
SET @SqlQuery = '
SELECT ulv.*, cau.CREATED_BY, cau.CREATED_DATE  from CORE.DEF ulv 
left join CORE.ABC cau 
on cau.id = ulv.id  
where
'

IF @DEF IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    SET @SqlQuery = @SqlQuery + ' ulv.id IN (' + REPLACE(@DEF, ',', ',') + ')';
END

IF @ABC IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    SET @SqlQuery = @SqlQuery + ' AND cau.abc IN (' + REPLACE(@ABC, ',', ',') + ')';
END

Just to clarify if I remove these params in procedures and just run the query without where filters it gives me correct result in code and dbeaver both
Unable to understand whats wrong with the query params, same are giving result from dbeaver while not from code
